# Decode output from SSH shell in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, ssh

I have this code written in dart(Flutter) that implements an SSH client using this package [SSH](https://pub.dev/packages/ssh).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ssh/ssh.dart';

void main() => runApp(Home());

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String out = "";

  void send() async {
    setState(() {
      out = "";
      print(out.codeUnits);
    });

    SSHClient client = new SSHClient(
      host: "192.168.10.88",
      port: 22,
      username: "Jesus",
      passwordOrKey: "******",
    );

    await client.connect();
    await client.startShell(
      ptyType: "vanilla",
      callback: (dynamic res) {
        setState(() {
          out += res;
          print(res.codeUnits);
          /*
          print output:
          [27, 91, 50, 74, 27, 91, 109, 27, 91, 72, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 32, 87, 105, 110, 100, 111, 119, 115, 32, 91, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 32, 49, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 57, 48, 52, 49, 46, 51, 56, 56, 93, 27, 93, 48, 59, 67, 58, 92, 87, 73, 78, 68, 79, 87, 83, 92, 115, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 51, 50, 92, 99, 111, 110, 104, 111, 115, 116, 46, 101, 120, 101, 7, 27, 91, 63, 50, 53, 104, 10]
          [40, 99, 41, 32, 50, 48, 50, 48, 32, 77, 105, 99, 114, 111, 115, 111, 102, 116, 32, 67, 111, 114, 112, 111, 114, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 32, 65, 108, 108, 32, 114, 105, 103, 104, 116, 115, 32, 114, 101, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 100, 46, 10]
          [27, 91, 53, 50, 88, 10]
          */
        });
      },
    );

    //await client.writeToShell("cd\r\n");
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 5),
      () async => await client.closeShell(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("SSH")),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Send Command"),
                onPressed: send,
              ),
              Text(out),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, when i run the program and start the client, the output from the emulated shell is garbage, like so
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8mB4.jpg)
.

I think i need to do some kind of decoding to interpret the escape character "27", but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = utf8.decode(await sshClient.run(command));
```

try this you will able to convert sshSession output into String format.